# Different Background color for each view in ASP.NET MVC using CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, background-color

I'm trying to build a website using ASP.NET MVC 4. My project came with a css file which affects all my views that make use of a main layout (_Layout.cshtml). I want to be able to use one of the three different background colors depending on the view and I need help with that. Here is what I have so far:

```
/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#body {
    background-color: #eb6f5c;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#body#Geldi {
    background-color: #a0f3ab;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

#body#Login {
    background-color: #e8f3a0;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}


footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Research did not get me further than this. All my pages are still pinkish red (#eb6f5c). How can I tell Visual Studio that I want to use the "Geldi" body type or the "Login" one for a particular view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think you can use that particular CSS selector (I think it translates to select element with ID="body" and also ID="Login" (or "Geldi"), but CSS is not my strength).  If you are setting it for the body tag of the page, get rid of the `#body` and just use `body` since you can select by HTML element name. So instead: `body#Login` and `body#Geldi`

After that, it would probably be best to use ViewData, and set it in your subview (Login view or something), which will then make it available to your Master View

For instance:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<body id='@(ViewData["PageId"] ?? "")'>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

Login.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["PageId"] = "Login";
}

<div id='content'>
    <!-- All of your page content here and whatever -->
</div>
```

Comment: I got an error when I put that in:

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments

No idea what to do now.

Comment: I think that's going to work, first it only made my my header green on the "green page", then i put it in a div that already had an id of "body" and it turned white, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Also, if I remove the # in front of the parameterless body in the css file, my header becomes red also. But it doesn't look like I can use the other ones if I don't remove it. Should I just assign a PageId to all my views (there aren't that many of them anyway) and just delete the default part?

Comment: CSS isn't really my forté and I don't know exactly how your page is set up. Basically the PageId value is just a way to pass data to your _Layout.cshtml file if needed

Comment: Ok, thank you, I haven't worked out the details yet but I think this is the way to go. I will write my own layout next time with this setup, after I study a bit more html and css.